Where are all the in-level guns hidden?
After completing each stage of the campaign, a new weapon or piece of equipment is unlocked.  However, you are also able to find the guns in the stage; doing so will let you use it right away.
The first one (the shotgun) is called out for you in the gas station level (also called 'Shotgun') on a table at the hardware store.  I think I was only able to find one other gun during the campaign, but I'm curious where they're all hidden.  The maps are pretty detailed and fun to explore, but the equipment seems very well hidden!


